# Deployment of web application on different vms all together

Tags: azure

I have a requirement where i have multiple vms, my web application is hosted on all vms. it is a cumbersome job to go and deploy application in each vm one by one.Is there a way to deploy application in all server(vms) at one shot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VM scale sets to deploy your applications. Just need to create only one image with the application installed in it. Then create multiple instances. See the description for [Azure VM Scale Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/overview#why-use-virtual-machine-scale-sets).

Comment: Thank you for reply. How it will work in case of update in application

Comment: @MansiGupta You can delete another and you can add the comment under my answer if you have questions. Generally, if you want to update the application, then you need to update the image. If it's just a little change, you can use the extension. You can take a look at the [Maintenance and update for virtual machines in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/maintenance-and-updates?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machine-scale-sets%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reply. How it will work in case of update in application.